# Python v3 ( Random password generator )

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is: how to generate a random password with a  length that varies from (8 to 12 characters) each time generated.

This is my code:

```
import string
import random

def randompassword():
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    size=8 
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size,12))

print(randompassword())
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only generate a length-4 password since range(8, 12) has 4 elements?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`size = 8; range(size, 12)` always returns array `[8,9,10,11]`, so you always get a password of length 4.
Instead, determine the size of this particular password using `randint` ahead of time:

```
import string
import random

def randompassword():
  chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
  size = random.randint(8, 12)
  return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size))
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was missing the randint function.

Comment: If it isn’t obvious, this will also work in Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

There are nuances to this question and certain solutions may cause `password weakness` problems. Consider the following nuances along with the solution alternative.

- Some answers employ `string.printable`, but this isn't a good idea since that contains **whitespace** characters. While they are not strictly illegal for passwords, you cannot easily see them and therefore cannot differentiate, say, a **tab** from several **spaces** (and so on). *Below I only employ lowercase letters & uppercase letters, digits and punctuation characters*.
- Randomly choosing from a set of characters based on **element-position** isn't random since the cardinality of each included **character-class** isn't uniformly distributed: **26** Lowercase letters; **26** Uppercase letters; **10** Digits; **32** Punctuation characters. Therefore generated passwords are likely to have more letters than punctuation characters and digits; and more punctuation characters than digits; (and so on). So if `random.choices()` is used (as in other answers), one should also employ it's `weights=` and `cum_weights=` options, to eliminate aforementioned biases and even-out the distribution.
- That said, I encourage use of Python's `secrets` module rather that its `random` module for this use case. From their [documentation on random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> Warning: The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used
> for security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the
> [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module.

Here is one **functionally-oriented** solution using **Python-3**. It uses `secrets.choice()` only. **It doesn't totally solve the random problem** (other nuances remain), but it does improve selection-distribution to reduces bias:

```
>>> import string, secrets

>>> char_classes = (string.ascii_lowercase,
                    string.ascii_uppercase,
                    string.digits,
                    string.punctuation)

>>> size = lambda: secrets.choice(range(8,13))                  # Chooses a password length.
>>> char = lambda: secrets.choice(secrets.choice(char_classes)) # Chooses one character, uniformly selected from each of the included character classes.
>>> pw   = lambda: ''.join([char() for _ in range(size())])     # Generates the variable-length password.
```

**DEMO**: Generate 10 variable-length password-strings using characters uniformly selected from each of our character classes:

```
>>> for i in range(1,11):
>>>    p = pw()
>>>    print('%i) %i chars :: %s' % (i,len(p),p))
 1) 11 chars :: IwWNEAUmnJt
 2) 10 chars :: ;N/'tO6RTv
 3)  8 chars :: l=5.2CDh
 4) 10 chars :: V0=I+A`t2Q
 5) 12 chars :: PQm8:f,#56"9
 6) 10 chars :: KOdx9~%r;F
 7) 11 chars :: <?67U8}3>F{
 8) 11 chars :: G$5y~3fE7o*
 9) 10 chars :: 70,|=Rexwn
10)  8 chars :: &31P^@cU
```

Finally, while we used the `secrets` module here, something similar could be done using `numpy` and `numpy.random`. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As stated below the `string.printable` string contains characters that can cause issues when used for passwords. Instead of relying on this build-in set you're probably better off defining a custom set of usable characters. Don't forget about characters as space which are LHF to improving the strength of a password. Just be sure to handle heading/tailing spaces as the UI could potentially strip the input of a user preventing them from entering a valid password.

```
import random
import string

def randompassword():
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(random.randint(8, 12))])
```

Comment: string.printable contains \t \n and a few others that are not suitable for passwords.

Comment: @IstvanSzekeres That's a valid point, I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's only printing 4 characters due to`size = 8` and `range(size,12)`. This translates to range(8, 12) = 4 characters. You could increase the second number to allocate for a larger range to print random characters for like so

```
import string
import random

def randompassword():
    chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    size= 8
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(size,20))

print(randompassword())
```

Also be sure to check out python's random documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Answer (score 1):

> **string.ascii_letters** #considers all the small case and large case alphabets.
>   **string.digits** #considers 0 to 9 digits.
>   **string.punctuation** #considers the special characters like symbols.
>   **random.choice** #considers to randomly pick from the given data.
>   **range(random.randint(6, 12))** #considers to pick a random int range from the given data.
>   **print(generator_pw())** #prints random generated password.

```
import random, string

def generator_pw():
    pwd = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    return "".join(random.choice(pwd) for x in range(random.randint(6, 12)))

print(generator_pw())
```

Answer (score 0):

`range(size,12)` only returns numbers between `size` (which you've hardcoded to 8) and 12, so your passwords will only be 4 characters long. Make that `... for x in range(size)`.